# Java JNLP self signing jars

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start, jar-signing

When i create an unsigned JWS (Java web start) app, user will have to confirm any action that might harm his system.
As i don't have money (nor need) for proper signing my JWS app, how can i (and, can i at all) create certificate for myself and self-sign my jars.
I want to prevent Java from asking for confirmation on any single "out-of-sandbox" action, but to ask user only once during initial startup "do you want to give full rights to this app"? Is that possible with self-signing the app.

Note: all my users trust me and my app, and they would be ok with "do you want to give all rights to this app" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your Java Web start work you need signed JARS.

But you don't need money for that.

Install this Eclipse plugin

[Eclipse Webstart Plugin.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webstart/)

You will just need to export as "Webstart". It will prompt you to sign the jars.

EDIT:

Demo

[DEMO](http://webstart.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I had no idea about this! I'll try it!